# Import/Export Wizard and quote delimiter issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Why I am getting the following error, and how can we fix it?

> Error 0xc0202055: Data Flow Task 1: The column delimiter for column "Col1" was not found.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

I'm using the latest version (18.11..) of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (`SSMS`) to import data from a 500MB text file that has `|` as a column terminator. As shown in the image below, I'm using Text Qualifier as double quotes `"` and there is no `|` character inside the `Col1` column, and the column is delimited by `|`.

[image]

Comment: Please show us the actual text of your `MyFile.txt` instead of describing it in prose.

Comment: Your screenshot shows you set the Text Qualifier to `*` but your post says it's `"`.

Comment: Your screenshot does not include the other fields in the _Flat File Source_ options, [such as the Row Delimiter and Column Delimiter options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/flat-file-connection-manager?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: @Dai thanks for pointing out the typo in screenshot. I've corrected it.

Comment: You can selected `Code page: 1252 (ANSI - Latin 1)` in your screen shot... but what's the actual encoding of your text file? If it's UCS-2 or UTF-16 encoding SSIS will be seeing "every other character" as 0x00 (ASCII NUL) and not reading the file in correctly.